# Proof of weak derivatives in Evans PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

In the textbook of Partial differential equation of Evans.

[image]

Why from $\int_U(v-\overline v)\phi dx=0$ for all $\phi \in C_c^\infty (U)$, we can get $v-\overline v=0$ a.e.?

How to prove it?

Thanks!

Comment: @Tomás But the proof of the lemma only assume $v \in L_{loc}^1(U)$. While in Boris-Reymand lemma, $V$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

First see $\S$ C.5 of Evans's book.

Now to prove the statement, we simply let $\phi(y)=\eta_\epsilon(x-y)$ and then apply Theorem 7 (ii). The main idea here is Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem.